# Segmented control to change pages in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, segmentedcontrol

I've been going through example after example trying to compare my project with others to see what I'm doing incorrectly however I have yet to find the answer. In short what I'm attempting to do for class is have a three button segmented control that will change the url that a `UIWebView` displays.

However, when the app is ran it crashes on launch with the following console output

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7f969ab2dd80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key appleWebView.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The following is my code:

**ViewController.M**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *appleSite1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.theScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(280, 1000.0);
}

- (IBAction)appleSite1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}


@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
//{
//    IBOutlet UIWebView myWebView;
//}
//

@end
```

I'm only testing with the one site (ebay) until I can figure out exactly what I'm missing. Obviously I'm a student and am learning so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you create the UiWebView anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solve your problem...

The crash is maybe caused by Interface Builder which is linking your UIWebView to a property (IBOutlet) named appleWebView. I think that you renamed `appleWebView` to `myWebView`.

To fixe this open the controller's xib (or storyboard), select the UIWebView, in the right panel open the connections inspector and remove the link to appleWebView.

Hope it helps!